# sending cookies with ajax request via fetch api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, csrf, fetch-api

In a nodeJs app, i am sending `multipart/form-data` to the server via ajax request. I am also using `csurf` package to guard against `csrf` attacks

**Problem**

When i submit my form without ajax request, everything works fine but when i submit my form using ajax request, i get `invalid csrf token` error on the server.

As far as i have understood the cause of this error, its because of cookies not sent with the request.

To send the cookies with ajax request, i set `credentials: 'same-origin'` in the `post` request made via `fetch api` but that didn't fix the issue. I also tried setting `credentials: 'include'` but that didn't make any difference.

**Question**

Is my understanding correct that this issue is because of cookies not being sent with ajax request and how can i fix this issue?

**Code**

```
let response = await fetch(requestUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multiplart/form-data'
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams(form)
});
```

Comment: do you see your csrf cookie when you inspect `document.cookie`? Inspect the cookies in your devtools > application > cookies, is the csrf set to httponly?

Comment: @exside i just logged it to the . console but nothing was displayed on the console.

Comment: I think that's your issue, the csrf cookie needs to be accessible via `document.cookie` for fetch to send it with its requests, is it set to http only?

Comment: @exside i am using `express-session` package for session management.  i inspected my cookies and there's one cookie with the name of `connect.sid` that is set by the domain that i am using and yes it is set to `http-only`

Comment: Did you explicitly set the `cookie` option of `csurf` to `true`? Otherwise it's not going to use a cookie... and if you did so, is your `cookie-parser` middleware set up properly?

Comment: @exside no i did not set the `cookie` option of `csurf` to `true`

Comment: Then it will use the session middleware for the csrf token and you will have to send it to your view that renders the form and have it in the form as a hidden input, check the example in the repo https://github.com/expressjs/csurf

Comment: @exside i am doing exactly that. csrf token is in the form as a hidden input.

Comment: when you inspect your POST request in the network tab of your devtools, is the csrf field present in the request body when you send the form via `fetch()`?

Comment: @exside Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197413/discussion-between-nick-and-exside).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `fetch()`/AJAX with `csurf`, you need to pass the CSRF token as a request header:

```js
// Read the CSRF token from a hidden input in the form
const token = document.querySelector('input[name="csrf-token"]').value;

// POST using the Fetch API
fetch('/<route.name>', {
  headers: {
    // pass the csrf token as a header
    'CSRF-Token': token
  },
  method: 'POST',
  body: {
    ...
  }
});
```